# Why my code runs faster if I build it in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++, codeblocks

I have created a small library (around 600 lines) in C++ in Codeblocks and I'm using OMP and O3 optimization to build it. When I try to build the same code through the terminal with a Makefile with exactly the same options (**-fopenmp -O3**) it runs around 3 times slower. I need to build it in various machines so I need to do the process through a terminal and not through Codeblocks. Why is this happening?
This is my Makefile if you're interested:

```
CC=g++ 
CFLAGS= 
LDFLAGS= -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++11 
SOURCES=main.cpp CNNFunctions.cpp     
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) EXECUTABLE=cnn

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: You should show us your C++ code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Makefile` is wrong. The optimization flags are relevant mostly at compile time. Try at least:

```
CXX=g++ 
CXXFLAGS=  -Wall -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++11 -mtune=native
LDFLAGS= -fopenmp
SOURCES=main.cpp CNNFunctions.cpp     
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) 
EXECUTABLE=cnn

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
       $(LINK.cpp) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

Optimization might matter at link time for *Link-Time Optimization*, for that use `CXX=g++ -flto` and `LDFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS)`

Comment: That's what I initially thought too, but `-fopenmp` is documented as implying `-pthread`, and `-pthread` is also needed at link time. A quick test shows that `-fopenmp` does indeed have an effect at link time.

Answer (score 5):

Because, contrary to your claim, you're not building it with the exact same options.

Your `CFLAGS` are empty, and those are the flags you're using for the compilation. You cannot resolve that by the time you get to the linking step.

Comment: So I need to put the flags in CFLAGS too?

Comment: @pap-x Not only that, you don't need to have then in `LDFLAGS`, so you could simply move them. (Edit: actually, `-fopenmp` might be needed at link-time too, but at least `-std=c++11` and `-O3` don't need to be.)

Comment: Yes I had tried to move them to CFLAGS and it didn't work. It needs to be in both.